# Cannot post a question because "It does not meet our quality standards"

Tags: support, quality-filter

If I want to post question, it displays the following:

Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

```
* It does not meet our quality standards.
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the text of the question?

Comment: It is due to [an automatic filter to rule out SPAM and other low quality questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards). If after reading that link, you are still not sure on how to make the question pass the filter, you should post the title and the text of the exact question you were about to ask, and maybe we can help you figure out how to rephrase the question better.

Comment: It appears that one of the secret criteria for "low-quality" is "too concise". Adding more verbiage to your question or answer should circumvent the filter. Perhaps it also takes rep into account, since I've given some one-line answers that didn't trigger it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Willie Wong said, [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards) should provide you with a description of the quality filter and suggestions on how to improve your question.

> Make sure your question has
>
> - a clear title
> - a reasonable explanation of what your question is, sharing your research on the matter
> - correct use of English and actual sentences
>
> If your question is so brief that it could be looked up in a dictionary or reference book/site trivially, it might not be a good fit on our network.